# Как побороть ошибку "Request did not return bytes" в Twisted

Tags: python-3.x, twisted

Добрый день!
Как победить ошибку `Request did not return bytes` в Twisted (Python 3). Начиная с простого примера взятого с их официальной документации:

```
from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Simple(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    def render_GET(self, request):
        return "<html>Hello, world!</html>"

site = server.Site(Simple())
reactor.listenTCP(8080, site)
reactor.run()
```

Тут всё решается заменой `"<html>Hello, world!</html>"` на `b"<html>Hello, world!</html>"`. Но если взять вывод json:

```
import json
from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Simple(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    def render_GET(self, request):
        result = json.dumps(['foo', {'bar': ('baz', None, 1.0, 2)}])
        return result

site = server.Site(Simple())
reactor.listenTCP(8080, site)
reactor.run()
```

Тут уже такое не работает.

И как, вообще, избавиться от постоянного добавления b вначале строки, т.к. с этим костылем код писать совсем грустно.

Comment: Это не костыль, это надо возвращать байты — вот и возвращайте байты. Любую строку можно закодировать в байты, дописав после неё `.encode('utf-8')` (или любую другую кодировку на ваш вкус)

Comment: Спасибо! Но в том же python2 этого не требуется и всё нормально работает. Гораздо удобнее.

Comment: В том же Python 2 все строки по умолчанию байтовые, в Python 3 уже юникодные и их надо предварительно кодировать в байты. И это на самом деле гораздо, гораздо лучше, просто вы это ещё не понимаете по неопытности :)

Comment: Хотя добавлять всякий хлам действительно неудобно. Но не в курсе как это можно упростить в Twisted